# How to Get Mac Address of Client Using SQL or PL/SQL in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to get MAC address of client computer using SQL or PL/SQL 
in Oracle database 12c/11g.

Comment: What did you try so far, did you some effort?

Comment: @Sami - how easy do you think it is to read the client's MAC address in PL/SQL?

Comment: Do you use any of Oracle's Middleware products like Forms, ADF, MAF during your db sessions?

Answer (score 1):

SYS_CONTEXT() can give some limited information about the connecting session using  from the `userenv` namespace.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions199.htm#SQLRF51825).

You can get the IP_ADDRESS of the client, and  TERMINAL which is the OS identifier.

```
SQL> select sys_context('userenv', 'terminal') from dual
  2  /

SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','TERMINAL')
---------------------------------
pts/1

SQL>
```

This isn't the MAC address, but the real question is why do you think you need it? Read [this OTN Forum thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2208939), I think you'll find it interesting (particularly Billy Verreynne's contribution).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that the MAC address is available from the client login.  Many of the specific things that you can get at are contained within the SYS_CONTEXT

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions165.htm